# how to call function using name such as "function someName(){}"?

Tags: javascript

I have a name of a private function in JavaScript as a string, how do I call that function?

```
var test = function () {

    this.callFunction = function(index) {
        return this["func" + index]();
    }

    function func1() { }
    function func2() { }
    ...
    function funcN() { }
}

var obj = new test();
obj.callFunction(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

`func1` and friends are local variables, not members of the object. You can't call them like that (at least not in any sane way).

Define them with function expressions (instead of function declarations) and store them in an array.

```
var test = function () {

    this.callFunction = function(index) {
        return funcs[index]();
    }
    var funcs = [
         function () {},
         function () {},
         function () {}
    ];
}

var obj = new test();
obj.callFunction(0);
```

Comment: `obj.callFunction(0);` is undefined. `return funcs[index]();` needs to be `return funcs[index];`

Comment: @Asad: No.`obj.callFunction(0);` is `undefined` because none of the functions in `funcs` return a value. If you only have `return funcs[index];`, then you are only returning the reference to the function and you would have to call like `obj.callFunction(0)();` which is worse IMO. *edit:* Just saw your answer, I guess the OP will choose what he likes best. But the name `callFunction` suggests that the function should actually call another function, not just return a reference.

Comment: I missed that "private" part. Good answer!

Comment: @Asad — That would return the function instead of calling the function. The question appears to be trying to call the function.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, it is undefined because the functions don't have a return value. I thought the OP wanted to return the functions (and optionally invoke them by doing `obj.callFunction(0)();`) Why do you think that is worse?

Comment: @Asad: I assume the OP is a beginner in JS and this just looked a bit too complex to me. But to be fair, I had in mind that the function is always called, hence always having to write `obj.callFunction(0)()` would be worse...

Answer (score 1):

As your code stands, the functions are not present as properties of the instance. What you need to do is create them as properties of the context.

```
var test = function () {

    this.callFunction = function(index) {
        return this["func" + index];
    }

    this.func1 = function() { }
    this.func2 = function() { }
    ...

}

var obj = new test();
obj.callFunction(1)();
```

Comment: Then they wouldn't be private any more. That also has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: @Quentin I usually refer to `this` as the scope. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes. `this` is the context. The scope is a factor of the function (and its parent functions).

Answer (score 0):

you can use eval

```
var test = function () {

    this.callFunction = function(index) {
        return eval("func" + index + '()');
    }

    function func1() {
        return 1;
    }

    function func2() {
        return 2;
    }

    function funcN() { }
};

var obj = new test();
obj.callFunction(2);
```

**eval is evil**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private array of functions:

```
var test = function() {
    var func = [
        function() { return "one" },
        function() { return "two"; }
    ]
    this.callFunction = function(index) {
        return func[index]();
    }
}

var obj = new test();
var ret = obj.callFunction(1);
console.log(ret);​
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V8FaJ/